# Given 2 is a primitive root mod 19, find all solutions to x^12 ≡ 7 (mod 19) (a) x^12 ≡ 6 (mod 19)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

I'm stuck on (another) problem under Number Theory. There are quite a few gaps on what was covered in my class so I'm having quite a bit of trouble. Could you please help me solve the following problem?

**2 is a primitive root mod 19. Using this information, find all solutions to x^12 ≡ 7 (mod 19) and x^12 ≡ 6 (mod 19)**

I think I would have to make use of the powers of 2 to solve this, but I can't get any further than that.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could start by listing out the powers of 2 $\pmod{19}$...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write $x=2^p$ (why ?) then you get $2^{12p}\equiv 2^y\pmod{19}$ where $y$ correspond to the representation for $7$ and $6$.

Then you get solve $12p\equiv y\pmod{18}$ (why ?)

Comment: This would solve to give k = 2, right? And then would the next one be 2^14 = 6 (mod 19) => 2^12k = 2^14 (mod 18)? I might have set this up wrong because I can't find a solution for 12k = 14 (mod 18). Any input? –

Comment: Yes, this is it, for $x^{12}=7$ you have $6$ solutions and for $x^{12}=6$ there are none.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

So you're given that $2$ has order $18\bmod 19$. In particular, $7\equiv 2^6\mod 19$.

Any solution can be written as $2^k$, where $k$ is unique module $18$. The equation can be rewritten as
$$2^{12k}\equiv 2^6 \mod 19\iff 12k\equiv 6\mod 18\iff 2k\equiv 1\mod 3.$$

Can you continue?

Comment: This would solve to give k = 2, right? And then would the next one be 2^14 = 6 (mod 19) => 2^12k = 2^14 (mod 18)? I might have set this up wrong because I can't find a solution for 12k = 14 (mod 18). Any input?

Comment: @Kami: For the first equation, you find $k\equiv 2\mod 3$, i.e. $k=2, 5, 8$, &c.  As to the second equation, $12k\equiv 14\pmod{18}\iff 6k\equiv 7\pmod 9$, and there's not necessarily a solution, as $6$ is not a unit mod. $9$. Indeed $6$ has only three multiples mod. $9$: $\;6, 3$ and $0$.